# What is the difference between tf.matmul and tf.batch_matmul in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

For example if I have the following data:

```
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n, n])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n, n])
```

Is there any difference between the two operations?

```
res = tf.matmul(x,y)
res = tf.batch_matmul(x,y)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tf.batch_matmul` is deprecated in favor of `tf.matmul` in version 0.12 and later so no difference in later versions. Earlier versions required rank-2 inputs for `matmul` but allowed larger ranks for `batch_matmul`